# multiplying difference between two dates in days by float vectorized form

Tags: pandas, vectorization, timedelta, floating

I have a function which calculates the difference between two dates and then multiplies that by a rate. i would like to use this in a one off example, but also apply to a pd.Series in a vectorized format for large scale calculations. currently it is getting hung up at
(start_date - end_date).days
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

```
pddt = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)
def cost(start_date, end_date, cost_per_day)
    start_date=pddt(start_date)
    end_date=pddt(end_date)
    total_days = (end_date-start_date).days
    cost = total_days * cost_per_day
    return cost

a={'start_date': ['2020-07-01','2020-07-02'], 'end_date': ['2020-07-04','2020-07-10'],'cost_per_day': [2,1.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)

costs = cost(a.start_date, a.end_date, a.cost_per_day)

cost_adhoc = cost('2020-07-15', '2020-07-22',3)
```

if i run it with the series i get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

if I try to correct it by adding .dt.days then when I only use a single input i get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Comment: What version of Pandas/Python are you using? I just copied your function and able to get the answer without any errors. Running `cost('01/01/2020', '05/31/2020', 40)` returned me the answer as `6040`.

Comment: I have ammended the above to show clearly what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you can change the function

```
total_days = (end_date-start_date) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: if i understood the difference more I would !

Comment: How do you know that this solves the problem if you can't explain why?

Comment: coz when i run the code in all of my functions and in the example i gave above it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both variables are [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects, the expression `(end_date-start_date)` gives you a `timedelta` object [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). It holds time difference as days, seconds, and microseconds. To convert that to days for example, you would use `(end_date-start_date).total_seconds()/(24*60*60)`.

For the given question, the goal is to multiply daily costs with the total number of days. `pandas` uses a subclass of `timedelta` (`timedelta64[ns]` by default) which facilitates getting the total days (no total_seconds() needed), see [frequency conversion](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion). All you need to do is change the timedelta to dtype `timedelta64[D]` (D for daily frequency):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-02'], 
                   'end_date': ['2020-07-04', '2020-07-10'],
                   'cost_per_day': [2, 1.5]})

# make sure dtype is datetime:
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])

# multiply cost/d with total days: end_date-start_date converted to days
df['total_cost'] = df['cost_per_day'] * (df['end_date']-df['start_date']).astype('timedelta64[D]')
# df['total_cost']
# 0     6.0
# 1    12.0
# Name: total_cost, dtype: float64
```

Note: you don't need to use a `pandas.DataFrame` here, working with `pandas.Series` also does the trick. However, since `pandas` was created for these kind of operations, it brings a lot of convenience. Especially here, you don't need to do any iteration in Python; it's done for you in fast `C` code.

Comment: this solution is incorrect as it does not allow for the non DataFrame input, but im grateful for your help on understanding with the difference between timedelta and timedelta64[D] is ?

Comment: @lawrencenyc: by *incorrect* you mean *incomplete*? Seriously, you're right, there was not a lot of explanation... made an edit, let me know if that helps. Also note that you would want to avoid `pd.Series.apply` here since it would require iterating the series (not "vectorized").